# schedule powershell task using BAT file

Tags: windows, batch-file, powershell-2.0

This is not exactly a question but rather your views on whether I'm on the right track.

I want to schedule a powershell v2 script in windows 2008 R2. I can put C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe in the program/script textbox and the script name and the arguments in the "Add arguments(optional) textbox. My script accepts around 5 arguments and since the window is not resizable I have to scroll to view all of them. SO, I'm thinking about creating a BAT file with powershell script and the arguments in it and then schedule the BAT file.

So my question is whether this is the right approach? Wouldn't using the BAT file invoke DOS process which in turn would invoke the powershell executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is whether this is the right approach?

It is a technically valid approach. Whether it's right or wrong is subjective. If it functions properly, then it's technically "right" but you may lose the ability to see/capture any errors that are thrown; you may want to set up your PowerShell script to email your errors, or log them to a file (or even Event Viewer).

> Wouldn't using the BAT file invoke DOS process which in turn would invoke the PowerShell executable?

DOS has been dead for over a dozen years (so no DOS process will be invoked), but you are correct that an instance of `cmd.exe` would be started by Task Scheduler, and that in turn would start PowerShell.

Don't sacrifice long-term functionality/reliability because the window provided in Task Scheduler for entering the command line is inconvenient to you. There's no rule that says you can't write out the full command line in Notepad, and then copy/paste it into that little box. If the job works better with PowerShell being invoked directly instead of through a BAT file, do what works best for the functionality of the job itself.